# Linux c file operation to a character device file (/dev/uinput) fails

Tags: c, linux, file-io, kernel

I am in the middle of writing a user level C program, that reads a SPI device and translate the results to a keyboard event.

I am now trying to pass emulate key event to /dev/uinput. A weird thing is happening, file operation is failing.

**my_kbd.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/uinput.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PROG_NAME "c2h2_spi_kbd"
int fire_key(__u16);
int setup_uinputfd(const char *);
int close_uinputfd();
void write_uinput(__u16, __u16, __s32);

/*fd for uinput, we do need kernel to support uinput */
static int uinputfd = -1;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    puts("Welcome to use SPI keyboard program v0.1!");        

    uinputfd = setup_uinputfd(PROG_NAME);
    if(uinputfd != -1){
        fire_key(KEY_A);
    }else{
        puts("where is uinput ? do you have permission?\n");
    }

    close_uinputfd();
    exit(0);
}

int fire_key(__u16 key){
    write_uinput(EV_KEY, key, 1);
    return 0;
} 

void write_uinput(__u16 type, __u16 code, __s32 value){
    struct input_event ie;

    sleep(1);

    memset(&ie, 0, sizeof(ie));
    ie.type = type;
    ie.code = code;
    ie.value = value;

    if(write(uinputfd, &ie, sizeof(ie)) != sizeof(ie)) puts("ERR1");

    memset(&ie, 0, sizeof(ie));
    ie.type = EV_SYN;
    ie.code = SYN_REPORT;
    ie.value = 0; 

    if(write(uinputfd, &ie, sizeof(ie)) != sizeof(ie)) puts("ERR2");
}

int close_uinputfd(){
    close(uinputfd);
    return 0;
}

int setup_uinputfd(const char *name){
    int fd;
    int key;
    struct uinput_user_dev dev;

    fd = open("/dev/input/uinput", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_RDWR);
        if (fd == -1) {
            fd = open("/dev/misc/uinput", O_RDWR);
            if (fd == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", "uinput");
                perror(NULL);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
    memset(&dev, 0, sizeof(dev));
    strncpy(dev.name, name, sizeof(dev.name));
    dev.name[sizeof(dev.name) - 1] = 0;
    if (write(fd, &dev, sizeof(dev)) != sizeof(dev) || 
        ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY) != 0
        || ioctl(fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_REP) != 0) {
        goto setup_error;
    }

    for (key = KEY_RESERVED; key <= KEY_UNKNOWN; key++) {
        if (ioctl(fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, key) != 0) {
            goto setup_error;
        }
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, UI_DEV_CREATE) != 0) {
        goto setup_error;
    }
    return fd;

setup_error:
    fprintf(stderr, "could not setup %s\n", "uinput");
    perror(NULL);
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}


gcc -Wall my_kbd.c && sudo ./a.out
```

without `sleep(1);` I never have uinput event happen. with `sleep(1);`, this works perfect. (emulate keys output to focused program)

I do suspect this could be a cache problem, but `fsync(fd);` did not help. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that super user privilege isn't needed? If not, then try to run your program with "sudo ./yourprogram".

Comment: `gcc -Wall my_kbd.c && sudo ./a.out` when you sleep(1), everything is okay.

Comment: Can you say us what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: program exits successfully with no keyboard event happen, if i do sleep 1, the program emits a keyboard event (i.e. press a keystroke 'a') which is correct. i do find sleep(1) can be reduced to usleep(10000); thanks

Comment: Are you sure the right way to open "uinput" is with O_RDWR but not O_WRONLY？